# How to call graphql post request using volley library in android

Tags: android, post, android-volley, graphql

I want to call the graphql post request using Volley Library. I am already done for Json post service but i want to call graphql post service.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it with volley since parsing is a bit complicated when it comes to fragments and union types.  Here's a library that you can use https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android